# Nested formGroup bind Object to radio button

Tags: angular

I've got nested formGroup:

```
  this.form = fb.group({
  productName: ['ASD'],
  productWeightCategory: fb.group({
    id: [],
    categoryWeightName: []
  })
```

and template:

```
<form class="container col-md-2" [formGroup]="form"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">

    <div>
        <label for="productName">productName</label> <input
            class="form-control" id="productName" type="text" placeholder=""
            formControlName="productName"> <span class="small help-block"></span>
        <label for="radios">weigh category</label>
        <fieldset formGroupName="productWeightCategory">
            <div class="radio"
                *ngFor="let element of productWeightCategory; let ind=index;">
                <label> <input [value]="element" type="radio" name="id"
                    [checked]="ind===0"> {{element.categoryWeightName}} index
                    = {{ind}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid"
        value="submit">
</form>
```

and I'm unable to get value from radios.

Probably I missed something but I can't figure out what.

Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahg4jo?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as Christian suggested, remove the nested group, what you want is a form control. If you want the first item in array chosen, just set that when you are building form:

```ts
productWeightCategories = [
 new ProductWeightCategory(1, 'value 1'), 
 new ProductWeightCategory(2, 'value 2'), 
 new ProductWeightCategory(3, 'value 3')
];

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = fb.group({
    productName: ['ASD'],
    productWeightCategory: [this.productWeightCategories[0]]
  });
}
```

If you want to set it at later point, use `setValue` like suggested by Christian.

For your template use `[value]` like you did, and with the `formControlName="productWeightCategory"`. You also need to change the `name` attribute to the same, otherwise Angular will start complaining :)

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="radio" *ngFor="let element of productWeightCategories; let i=index;">
    <label> 
      <input [value]="element" type="radio" 
             name="productWeightCategory" 
             formControlName="productWeightCategory">
        {{element.categoryWeightName}} index = {{i}}
    </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Your **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hoej1f?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 2):

Remove `formGroupName="productWeightCategory"` and instead, on your input do this:

```
<input formControlName="productWeightCategory" [ngValue]="element" >
```

To set the `checked` property, you need to do it programatically because you're making use of the `ReactiveFormsModule`. That means the value of the FormControl must be the same as the one of the [ngValue]. You can do that in your component by setting the value of that FormControl. I'm not sure how you're getting your data but it would be something similar to this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.productWeightCategory.length; i++){
     if(condition)
         this.form.get('productWeightCategory').setValue(this.productWeightCategory[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `id: [ this.productWeightCategory[0].id ],` set the radio checked, and use `formControlName="id"` in radio input:

```
<fieldset formGroupName="productWeightCategory">
    <div class="radio" *ngFor="let element of productWeightCategory; let i=index;">
        <label> <input [value]="element.id" type="radio" name="id" formControlName="id"> {{element.categoryWeightName}} index = {{i}} </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And set categoryWeightName of submit before, use the `id` find it.

```
this.form = fb.group({
  productName: ['ASD'],
  productWeightCategory: fb.group({
    id: [ this.productWeightCategory[0].id ],
    categoryWeightName: []
  })
});
```

This can not be used the nested `FormGroup`

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bksctf?file=app/app.component.ts)